# Синонимизировать "исключения"?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть следующие метки:

- [try](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/try) (27 вопросов, нет описания)
- [try-catch](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/try-catch) (135 вопросов, есть описание)
- [exception-handler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exception-handler) (22 вопроса, нет описания)

Обозначают они, по сути, одно и то же — обработку исключений. `try-catch`, конечно, не всегда эквивалентно `try`, потому что есть `try-except`, однако зачем вообще их отличать? Обработка исключений остается собой в обоих случаях.

Поэтому предлагаю их синонимизировать в пользу метки [исключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: `try` - могут быть вопросы только про `try`. `try-catch` - вопросы только про `try` и `catch` (aka `except`) соответственно. `exception-handler` - может быть также про методы в классах/функции, допустим: `.catch(err => ...)` (Для JS).